# Hamcrest conditional matcher?

Tags: java, hamcrest

I have a parameterised test, one of the parameters is boolean to show whether the test should pass or fail.

In my test, i have a the following:

The parameters look like: `{0, 1, true}`

The test method contains:

`if (expectedResult) {
    assertThat(myList, matchesUsingMyCustomMatcher(otherList));
} else {
    assertThat(myList, not(matchesUsingMyCustomMatcher(otherList.subList(start, end))));
}`

What i don't want to do is to write an if-else statement. Thus my question: is there a conditional matcher? E.g.:
`assertThat(myList, ifMatcher(expected, matchesUsingMyCustomMatcher(otherList)));`

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly, but ... mathematically, "if a then b" is equivalent to "(not a) or b", so will it work to use an `anyOf` in combination with a `not` matcher?

Comment: There's a `Condition` class described at http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/.  Maybe that's what you need?

Comment: @ajb Thank you, i will have a look at Condition. Also I edited my post to make it more clear what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can check from the source code, [Condition](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/5f79ba7f0c15871f02a95c622c954eefedfcf183/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/Condition.java) doesn't do the trick. You can play with logical conditions as follows:

```
assertThat(myList,  
     either( allOf(is(expectedResult), matchesUsingMyCustomMatcher(otherList)) ) 
     .or( allOf(not(is(expectedResult)), not(matchesUsingMyCustomMatcher(otherList.subList(start, end))) ) ) 
         );
```

But let me say that I cannot imagine a test in which you don't know if a flag value is true or false. If both scenario can happen, the two tests must be written.